# Applying a row-based filter in Excel (with numrows > 16,384)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the same question as was addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094767/applying-row-based-filter-instead-of-column-based-in-libreoffice-or-other-spread

In Excel 2016, I usually can filter by column [(just with the filter button in the data tab).](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2016/filtering-data/1/)

I would like to filter the other way, by row.

My dataset is around 100 columns x 20,000 rows, [so it's too large to be transposed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

In practice, I'll just load the data up with Python/Jupyter and filter there. Or I'll just eat a few minutes and filter by hand.

But it would be great to do it right in Excel. Any solutions?

Comment: Cannot be done with Excel. Data filters only work vertically.

Comment: What do you mean by Row Based Filter? Share  Sample data with us to understand the Row based may be you are taking about a Record !!

Comment: Possibly you are talking about multiple criteria to Filter !